# Bash: replace specific newline with space

Tags: bash

I have numerous files with extension .awesome containing lines like the following:

```
something =
[51,42,12]
```

Where **something =* is in all the files as well as **[** (numbers vary.)

I would like to get rid of the newline, but don't know how. I came across **tr**, but worry it would replace all newlines. My files contain multiple newlines that I would like to retain (only change this newline.) I've been able to successfully to find and replace in the past with sed, but am having specifically with the special characters (\n and =.) In addition, I'm reading that sed is line by line and cannot handle something like this.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU **sed** solution:

Sample `test.awesome` file contents:

```
some text
another text
something =
[51,42,12]

text
text
```

---

The job:

```
sed '/something =/{N; s/\n/ /;}' test.awesome
```

The output:

```
some text
another text
something = [51,42,12]

text
text
```

Comment: It says, "sed: 1: "/something =/{N; s/\n/ /}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'"
This appears to be an issue for Mac users.

Comment: @MelanieShebel, add semicolon right after the subcommand `sed '/something =/{N; s/\n/ /;}' test.awesome`